# Update the state of object in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]I am new to react js. Here, I do have a functionality where there are three diff rows that can be added or removed. I have a reducer which is like,

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 'L0',
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
    Medium: [
        {
            id: 'M0',
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            level: 'Medium'
        }
    ],
    High: [
        {
            id: 'H0',
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            level: 'Tough'
        }
    ],
```

SO, Here, I want to have this as a generic,so, I am trying to add objects on click of the plus and remove on - . So,

Here, I am adding using ,

```
const tempObj = {
      id: tempvar + id,
      technologyId: 0,
      technology: temp[0].technology,
      type: type,
      count: '',
      level: addtype
    }
```

I create this object now depend upon the addType I add it in that particular array.

I do it using this way,

```
const addData = [...this.props.lowData[addtype], tempObj];

    this.props.addNewTech(addData);
```

So, Here this `...this.props.lowData[addtype]` returns an object not an array, is this the problem ? If yes, It should return an array not the object but how is this returning the object and not an array.
My props.lowData is like ,

an object with three different arrays, I mean same as that of the reducer .,But every time I add it adds that element in the `Low` array only and not in the medium or high. Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: what does `this.props.lowData` looks like. can you post the screen shot of it?

Comment: sure I can post it.

Comment: @Shivam added the lowData please check

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? Also show the respective action and reducer code.

Comment: Actually, On click of add button I just want to add an element to the respective  array, like, If I add an element in Low then it should be added in the Low array and same for others.But right now, it gets added in the Low every time.

Comment: Please post the respective action creator and reducer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182764/discussion-between-shivam-and-ganeshk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the reducer you are only updating the `Low` property. You need to check what property needs to update. For that you can pass `addtype` to your action creator like so

```
this.props.addNewTech({ addData, addtype });
```

And then in action creator

```
export function addNewTech(data) { 
  return {
     type: ADD_NEW, 
     data //is equavalent to data: data (ES6)
  } 
}
```

And then in reducer dynamically update the object

```
    case ADD_NEW: 
      return { 
        ...state, 
        //here choose the property to be updated dynamically
        //replace Low: action.data with below line
        [action.data.addtype]: action.data.addData, 
        error: false, 
      }
```

**Note here `[action.data.addtype]: action.data.addData`  we are using computed property names in ES6.

Comment: Excellent answer shivam . Thanks a lot for your time :-)